# Selected Simple Product as default on product grid

Tags: product

I have lots of group and simple products but I mostly search simple products to edit qty and price. I need to select 'Type - Simple Products' to be able to see only simple products on search result

How can I make the 'Type - Simple Products' is already selected as default on manage products grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would copy `\Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid` to `app/code/local/Mage` and edit `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php:169`

```
$this->addColumn('type',
    array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Type'),
        'width' => '60px',
        'index' => 'type_id',
        'type'  => 'options',


        'default' => 'simple' // ADD THIS <---------------


        'options' => Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_type')->getOptionArray(),
));
```

Comment: Can I know where '\Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid' to copy? Thanks!

Comment: Yes you can. In the same directory where it was before, so in this case: Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php ... [In the magento wiki it is described](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_create_a_local_copy_of_app_code_core_mage)

Comment: I think our product grid is controlled by an extension I contacted the extension company but I learn few things Thank you! I will update this question later and choose answer

Comment: Sadly, the extension company asked $ for this edit.. not happy to pay for this update so I still choose 'Simple Product' whenever I search item Thank you for reply!

Comment: Whatever your extension does, have a look on https://github.com/magento-hackathon/GridControl maybe this solves your problem and you can throw this extension away. Beside this, you can overwrite this extension as well.